# Remap Java calls in JavaScript Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, minecraft, nashorn, minecraft-forge

I am currently trying to make JavaScript support for the game "Minecraft" using [Nashorn](https://bitbucket.org/adoptopenjdk/jdk8-nashorn/src). My goal is to give users the ability to create their own commands and features.
For the most part it is working fine so far but the problem is that Minecraft's code is obfuscated when using it with [Forge](http://files.minecraftforge.net/).

For that reason all field and method calls have to be re-mapped with their corresponding [srg names](https://github.com/CCBlueX/FileCloud/blob/master/LiquidBounce/srg/mcp-stable_22.srg).

Example: `mc.thePlayer.swingItem();` to `mc.field_71439_g.func_71038_i();`

I am able to inject code into the Nashorn library using [Mixin](https://github.com/SpongePowered/Mixin) and I have already made a parser for the srg file. In a nutshell, what I need is the method I can use to replace `thePlayer` with `field_71439_g` or `swingItem()V` with `func_71038_i()V` before actually executing the code.

I have already tried finding the proper methods for hours.

https://github.com/CCBlueX/LiquidBounce1.8-Issues/issues/2649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Just inject into this methods of "jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.AbstractJavaLinker"

**Remap methods:**

`addMember(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject;Ljava/util/Map;)V`

**Remap fields:**

`addMember(Ljava/lang/String;Ljdk/internal/dynalink/beans/SingleDynamicMethod;Ljava/util/Map;)V`

`setPropertyGetter(Ljava/lang/String;Ljdk/internal/dynalink/beans/SingleDynamicMethod;Ljdk/internal/dynalink/beans/GuardedInvocationComponent$ValidationType;)V`

Answer (score 0):

## You need MCPbot

*Or rather, its mappings exports.*

Note that MCPbot, as its name implies, is a *bot.* Specifically one on an IRC channel so that mod developers can go "hey I figured out what `func_12345_a` does" and tell the bot, giving it a human-readable name, named parameters, and javadoc and the next build of Forge will include these updated mappings for modders to use.

(The "MCP" part stands for "Minecraft Coder Pack.")

You can find exports of the SRG name mappings [on the MCPbot website](http://export.mcpbot.bspk.rs) of which you'll need both csv files: Fields and Methods (as they're exported separately).

I will note, however, that including these mappings in your mod will probably violate copyright and you should check with Prof Mobius before using them in this manner.

Comment: Thanks for your answear, but that's not the problem. I already have the srgs. I just need to replace the fields and methods from `thePlayer` to `field_71439_g` **in the JavaScript**. So that the Script can work with "obfuscated" Minecraft.

Comment: Is your problem: "what are the translations" or "how do I replace strings?"

Comment: No, my problem is that I need to **remap** all field and method calls **of the JavaScript**. The JavaScript file will be compiled to bytecode. The method and field calls will be translated to InvokeDynamic Nodes they call the the bootstrap method. The problem is that I need to find a way to remap them. I need the **class** (_target class of field or method_) and the **name** (_field or method name_)... That would be enough to remap them...

Comment: So, you lookup the names in the MCPbot exports and do a string replacement. I'm not sure what the trouble is.